# WS2812 on LPC11C24 with light_ws2812

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller

I'm trying to get the WS2812 working on the NXP LPC11C24. 
I have done all things that are listed in the readme but I have problems with the following

```
Set code memory wait states to zero. Important: The library will not work if there are one or more code memory waitstate cycles. 
This may limit your code clock to 30 Mhz or lower on most Cortex-M0 controllers.
```

The LED stripe is shining in different colours than I programmed and I think the wait states are the reason.

I've tried the following two things, but none of them helped.

1.) Set FLASH access time in clocks

```
Chip_FMC_SetFLASHAccess( FLASHTIM_50MHZ_CPU )
```

2.)  Place the function that writes the data into the main RAM region

```
 __RAMFUNC(RAM) void ws2812_sendarray(uint8_t *ledarray,int length);
```

How can I set the wait states down to zero?

Comment: is wait states your problem?  it is a PITA to get those leds working, you really need to look at the data stream with a scope to see what is being produced and how is this library you have generating the signal.  Ideally you want to use logic, you cant really bit bang your way through this, so on stm32 parts they can use mosi on the spi interface, dont know what the nxp peripherals look like and if they can be repurposed to generate this kind of stream or if you use a timer instead.

Comment: as far as wait states you have to read the documentation for the part and insure you can run at zero wait states, your main clock speed often has to be running slower for that to work.  but each mcu (family) is dfferent.

Comment: NXP's site is down right now I cant get at the documentation...